# Granting Permission to Registry

Tags: c#, windows, registry, console-application

I am granting permission for **NETWORK SERVICE** to access a registry key that I need to access via a console application which I run as **NETWORK SERVICE**. Here is how I create the key and Grant permission.

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
            RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
            rs = key.GetAccessControl();
            rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule("NETWORK SERVICE", RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));
            key.SetAccessControl(rs);
            key = key.CreateSubKey("RM", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
            key = key.CreateSubKey("CSVExtraction", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
            key.SetValue("Failure Tally", "0");
```

But when I try to setValue to the key using the following code I am getting error. The code that I use to set value is given below.

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
            key = key.CreateSubKey("RM", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
            key = key.CreateSubKey("CSVExtraction", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
key.SetValue("Failure Tally, "1");
```

But Here I am getting an error saying access to HKLM/LOCAL MACHINE/SOFTWARE denied. But I have added access rule using the above code. But when I go and check the access manually the access is added to the WOW6432node.

Comment: Its mostly because, the application running with the logged in user is not a member of administrator group.
Try to run the application as Run as Administrator and try again.

Comment: The first piece of code is run as Admin ie the granting permission part. I am granting permission to "NETWOR SERVICE". BUt when I try to access using second piece of code the error throws up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue can be solved by making 2 changes
1) while granting permission
Your Code:  rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule("NETWORK SERVICE", RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));
            key.SetAccessControl(rs);

Edit it to be:

```
rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule("NETWORK SERVICE", RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
key.SetAccessControl(rs);
```

This is made to ensure the permissiom you give is inge=herited to sub trees.

2) You dont need to open key by key, instead you can access your desired key by writing

```
string registryFolderStructure =@"SOFTWARE\RM\CSVExtraction";
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(registryFolderStructure, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
```